# Unknown column 'Productsid' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I need a second set of eyes.  I know the error message is saying that Productsid cannot be found in my table. I cannot find what I need to change.
Here is my the method in my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("orderItems")]
        public IActionResult OrderItems(string name, string quantity, string product)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == name);
            var product_info = _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == product);
            if(product_info.quantity < Int32.Parse(quantity))
            {
                TempData["Quantity"] = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Orders");
            }

            Users_Has_Products user_products = new Users_Has_Products();
            user_products.users_id = user.id;
            user_products.products_id = product_info.id;
            user_products.quanitity = Int32.Parse(quantity);
            user_products.created_at = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Users_Has_Products.Add(user_products);
            _context.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Orders");
        }
```

Here is my Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ecommerce.Models
{
    public class Users_Has_Products
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int users_id { get; set; }
        public int products_id { get; set; }
        public int quanitity { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }

        public Users Users {get; set;}

        public Products Products {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Here is my db table
[image]

Comment: `Products_id` vice `Productsid`?

Comment: @radarbob, where is Productsid coming from?

Comment: some part you don't show. search the whole project for "Productsid" (note the quotes!)

Comment: @TaW, I mean where is my code or the table is Productsid?

Comment: it's coming from your question title! IOW, this strongly suggests a typo - a missing underscore - somewhere in your code, as @TaW suggests.